# Как передать значение переменной из одного скрипта в другой?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть объект с полем скорость (speed). Я хочу, чтобы другие объекты могли использовать её значение, то есть, по факту, иметь доступ к переменной скрипта (по разным причинам это может понадобиться).

Как я могу получить доступ к переменной объекта, чтоб все изменения, которые в нем произошли, можно было получить из другого объекта?

---

<sub>Вопрос переведен с https://stackoverflow.com/q/13891892/6104996</sub>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Есть несколько способов сделать это.

Если вы хотите получить значение `speed` из компонента, который прикреплен к объекту с именем, предположим `MyObject`:

```
public class SpeedController : MonoBehaviour
    public float speed;
    // Для ограничения только на чтение и запретить запись - можно использовать "Свойство"
```

то в другом компоненте вы можете сделать следующее:

```
// Найти объект по имени
GameObject go = GameObject.Find("MyObject");
// взять его компонент где лежит скорость
SpeedController speedController = go.GetComponent<SpeedController>();
// взять переменную скорости
float courrentSpeed = speedController.speed;
```

**Замечание**: если нейдется объект с таким именем или их будет много - то это может привести к плачевнм последствием. Также нужно помнить, что операция `Find` довольно медленная. И, например, в `Update` лучшее её не использовать.
Лучше найти объект при старте и только потом уже использовать.

---

Самый при самый неудобный способ (да и, в принципе, неправильный, но действующий) - это объявить переменную `speed` типа `SpeedController` в каждом классе. Перетащить в это поле объект в эдиторе. Тогда сможете наблюдать за состоянием переменной в любой момент. Но способ ужасный и не рекомендуемый

---

Еще способ создать синглтон, который будет содержать вашу переменную `speed`:

```
public class MyGlobalSpeedController {
    private static MyGlobalSpeedController instance = null;
    public static MyGlobalSpeedController SharedInstance {
        get {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new MyGlobalSpeedController ();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
    public float speed;
}
```

Тогда все классы смогут иметь доступ через него:

```
float currentSpeed = MyGlobalSpeedController.SharedInstance.speed
```

---

Еще можно объявить переменную статической и тогда она не будет привязана к объекту, а будет принадлежать классу

```
public class SpeedController : MonoBehaviour
    public static float speed;
```

доступ к ней прост:

```
var speedVal = SpeedController.speed;
Debug.Log(speedVal);
```

Раз вы пытаетесь сделать так, чтоб она была доступна всем остальным объектам, то, предполагаю, что объект с такой переменной у вас на сцене - один. Иначе этот способ становится бесполезным

---

Также можно использовать систему сообщений в *Unity*

Например [Component.SendMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Component.SendMessage.html). Он имеет 4 перегруженных метода

```
public function SendMessage(methodName: string, value: object = null, options: SendMessageOptions = SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver): void;
public function SendMessage(methodName: string, value: object = null, options: SendMessageOptions = SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver): void;
public function SendMessage(methodName: string, value: object = null, options: SendMessageOptions = SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver): void;
public function SendMessage(methodName: string, options: SendMessageOptions): void;
```

он вызывает метод с именем `methodName` в каждом `MonoBehaviour` на этом объекте, например:

```
go.SendMessage("GetFallingSpeed");
```

вызовет метод `GetFallingSpeed` на объекте `go`. А данный метод (GetFallingSpeed) возможно как раз и будет управлять параметром `speed`.

Не забудьте, что вам нужно получить доступ к `go` каким-либо образом, т.е. через `Find` или другим удобным способом.

---

<sub>Ответ переведен с дополнением с https://stackoverflow.com/a/13892844/6104996</sub>