# Как взять значение с какого-то файла/скрипта и использовать его в другом скрипте 2D

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть шахтер который копает руду, и по истечению времени я увеличиваю переменную gold, а потом вывожу эту переменную через функцию OnGUI которая в скрипте BarController но шахтеров у меня может быть много, а OnGUI один в одном скрипте, если я добавлю BarController на других шахтеров, OnGUI будет наложен на друг друга, как мне сделать так что бы OnGUI был один для всех шахтеров?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как передать значение переменной из одного скрипта в другой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549424/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9)

Comment: Так же возможно вам нужен какой-то игровой менеджер. Пустой объект, на котором будет скрипт управляющий другими объектами