# Как передать Email пользователя из базы SQLite в другую сцену в UNITY?

Tags: c#, unity3d, sqlite

подскажите пожалуйста как передать Email пользователя из базы SQLite на другую сцену, где будет осуществлен запрос для вывода информации о пользователе? Короче говоря я делаю вход в игру и при входе открывается профиль с информацией.
Получается я сделал вход, объявил переменную в скрипте входа, но как ее из использовать в другом скрипте не понял, пытался сделать вот так, но выдает много ошибок(

```
//объявление переменной в сцене входа
        public string _Email;
//запрос входа

      public void GetDB()
    {
        conn();
        try
        {
             _Email = InputEmail.text.ToString();
            string _pass = Inputpass.text.ToString();
                cmd_db = new SqliteCommand("Select id, from User Where Email='" + _Email + "' AND Password='" + _pass + "' ", con_db);
                rdr = cmd_db.ExecuteReader();
                if (rdr.HasRows & rdr != null)
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {  
                        Load_А(3);
                    }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
            print(ex.ToString());
        }
        Disconnect();
    }
```

Потом я сделал в скрипте профиля так:

```
 public Text Email_;
public InputField InputEmail;



login lg = InputEmail.GetComponent(typeof(login)) as login;
string Email_d=lg._Email;
Debug.Log(lg._Email);//выдает в этой строке ошибки
```

**Ошибки:**

```
Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements.
Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не срабатывает?
Я пробовал несколько вариантов отсюда: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549424/Как-передать-значение-переменной-из-одного-скрипта-в-другой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549424/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Comment: Разбейте проблему на части. 1: получение данных из БД, 2: передача данных в другую сцену. Первую удалось решить? Значит можете убрать все упоминания об этом из вопроса. Перефразируйте его: "Есть некое значение, как передать в другую сцену". Всё!

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки, вы либо поставили где-то лишние открывающие скобки, либо не закрыли скобки. Мы ваш код целиком не видим, поэтому помочь не сможем. Просто разберитесь с количеством скобок.

Comment: Классы и методы в C# надо называть с большой буквы. Сейчас непонятно, где у вас что.