# С# Unity [SerializeField], Как сделать ссылку на переменную

Tags: c#, unity3d, ссылка

Есть скрипт на объекте:

```
        [SerializeField] private float _maxHp;
        [SerializeField] private float _itemRegenHp;
if (_curHp < _maxHp)
        _regenHp = _str * 0.7f + _itemRegenHp;
        else
        _regenHp = 0;
```

Цель: из другого скрипта изменить переменные _maxHp и _itemRegenHp.

Я знаю, что можно реализовать ссылку через "static public" или "GetComponent<>();"
Но как мне известно, эти методы не оптимизированы и при частом использовании превратят код в кашу, пожирающую память, к тому же не читаемую. В отличие от "[SerializeField] private".

Я только учу теорию, постепенно закрепляя практикой.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/549425/191482

Comment: У вас каша в голове. какие-то неоптимизированные методы, [SerializeField] private нарушающий инкапсуляцию, но зато работающий,  static public который не привязан к классу.... это набор невзаимосвязанных вещей и к тому же попутно выдуманных о них какой-то миф

Comment: Я не претендую на то, что мои слова - истина. Я не просто так указал, что учу теорию. Само собой, моё мнение - сборник чужих мнений. И так уж сложилось ,что мнения влияющие на меня говорят одно и то же, аргументируя это довольно убедительно. Тем не менее, вопрос остаётся открытым.

Comment: Один из вариантов описан в ссылке выше........в целом, никто не мешает использовать `GetComponent` предварительно занеся ссылку на объект в переменную в методе Start или Awake и потом использовать эту переменную

Comment: Вот и вопрос. Как занести ссылку на объект в методе Start?

Comment: Найти через Find например, или FindGameObjectsWithTag или FindObjectOfType или куча способов через разные другие find описанных в документации))  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `[SerializeField] private` поля нарушает инкапсуляцию? Разве это не как раз таки способ, позволяющий оставить переменной как можно более закрытый модификатор доступа (в данном случае максимально закрытый), при этом сделав ее доступной в инспекторе Unity? Делать переменную публичной, то есть полностью открытой: не только для редактора юнити, но и для других классов -- будет хуже, разве не так?

Comment: @МаксимФисман почему вы решили, что я советую сделать поля публичными? Где об этом упоминание?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Нет, я просто спрашиваю, правильно ли я понял, что вы утверждаете, что SerializeField нарушает инкапсуляцию и если да, то что тогда лучше. "Делать поля публичными?" - это уже мое добавление, я не утверждаю, что это ваши слова. Потому что я не знал и не слышал такого про SerializeField

Comment: @МаксимФисман вообще, по факту, задание чего-либо из вне (а редактор - это есть что-то из вне)  вполне себе нарушение целостности

Answer (score 0):

В другом скрипте объявляешь скрипт где указаны переменные, а потом заносишь на него ссылку в Start():

```
private Player player;

private void Start(){
    player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
}
```

А потом можешь в этом же скрипте использовать любые переменные из скрипта Player (вместо Player в строке пишешь название скрипта откуда переносишь переменные), обязательно добавляя `player.` к перемене из скрипта:

```
player._curHp++;
```

**Не забудь в скрипте `Player` все эти переменные сделать публичными**, если не хочешь чтобы они показывались в инспекторе, просто добавляй перед объявлением переменной `[HideInInspector]`