# Unity. Как применить скопированный объект к Instantiate, затем в дальнейшем получить доступ из одного скрипта к другому?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Вот код первого скрипта, где есть `Instantiate`.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnPlayers : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameObject playerInstantiate;
    
    public static GameObject player;
    public float minX, minY, maxX, maxY;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 randomPosition = new Vector3 (Random.Range (minX, minY), Random.Range(maxX, maxY));
        playerInstantiate = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate (player.name, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

И как мне теперь передать значение playerInstantiate в другой скрипт?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как передать значение переменной из одного скрипта в другой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549424/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9)

Comment: вот, тут уже решили. просто замени Float на GameObject https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549424/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9