# Unity. Нужно обратиться к переменной из другого скрипта

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Возникли трудности с написанием скрипта. Объясню: есть string-переменная "cLevel" (например, она равна "Level1"). Есть игровой объект "Levels", в нём содержатся скрипты с названиями "Level1", "Level2", "Level3", "Level4" и т.д. То есть, название скрипта равно значению переменной "cLevel". Как-то нужно внутри объекта "Levels" найти скрипт, чьё название полностью совпадает со значением переменной "cLevel" и обратиться к bool-переменной "isEnabled" этого скрипта, присвоив значение "true". Как я могу это сделать? Я не очень понимаю принцип, как это можно реализовать. И по правильному пути ли я иду, может, есть способ проще? Заранее благодарю!

---

***Update**: я не могу просто обратиться к конкретному скрипту каждый раз, потому что каждый скрипт отвечает за уровень, текущий уровень меняется - скрипт тоже.*

Comment: присвойте объекту тег и делайте https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html

Comment: А что мне это дает? Немного не понял)
Да-да, я деревянный :)

Comment: Просто нужно каким-то образом внутри Levels найти компонент "Script", но чтобы его название совпадало со значением переменной "cLevel", так ещё и переменную внутри этого скрипта перевести в "true"

Comment: есть способ проще, называется полиморфизм подтипов

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как передать значение переменной из одного скрипта в другой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549424/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9)

Comment: Спасибо, но всё же отличие большое)